# How can I return an object that I create in my data service class through Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, model-view-controller, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I am trying to adhere to MVC practices and keep all the network code inside the data service class that I am using in my app. On one screen I have the user's name and username that needs to be displayed. When updating this, I am calling this function:

```
func grabUserData() -> User {
    REF_USERS.child(getCurrentUID()).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
        (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            let user = User(
                first:    userDict["firstName"]!, 
                last:     userDict["lastName"]!, 
                username: userDict["username"]!
            )
            return user
        } 
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error trying to return the user! It says:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function.

But the function clearly isn't void. So what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing your `grabUserData` *function* return value with the Firebase *closure* return value — the former is `User` but the latter is `Void` ;)

You are actually returning from this closure
— I'm now using a *explicit* return type to be clear:

```
{ 
    (snapshot) -> Void in
    if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,String> {
        let user = User(
            first:    userDict["firstName"]!, 
            last:     userDict["lastName"]!, 
            username: userDict["username"]!
        )
        return user
    }
}
```

which is passed as the last argument to the `observeSingleEvent` Firebase function. This is a *very* common mistake ;)

**Completion handler**. A standard pattern here is to *return* the desired `User` via a *completion handler* instead. This solution nicely models the *asynchronous* nature of network requests such as Firebase database calls. For instance:

```
func grabUserData(completion: @escaping (User?) -> Void) {
    REF_USERS.child(getCurrentUID()).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { 
        (snapshot) in
        if let userDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            let user = User(
                first:    userDict["firstName"]!, 
                last:     userDict["lastName"]!, 
                username: userDict["username"]!
            )
            completion(user) // Returns user!
        } else {
            completion(nil) // User not found!
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in your data service *client code*, call it like this:

```
grabUserData() { 
    (user) in
    if let user = user {
        print("Grabbed user: \(user)")
    } else {
        print("User not found!")
    }        
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks - I just implemented it and it works perfectly. The only suggestion Xcode has was to add "@escaping" to the completion handler because it must escape the closure. Thanks, Paulo!