# Firebase Upload URL to real time database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload image url from Firebase Storage to Realtime database.

Here's the code

```
  @IBOutlet weak var jobTitle: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var companyName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var jobLocation: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView1stPoster: UIImageView!
var imageUploaded = Data()
var URLtoRealtime = ""

 func addPost() {
    ref.child("Poster").childByAutoId().setValue(["jobName": jobTitle.text as Any,
                                                 "companyTitle": companyName.text as Any,
                                                 "jobLocation": jobLocation.text as Any,
                                                 "firstPoster": URLtoRealtime as Any,
                                                /*,
         "timeStamp":[".sv":"timestamp"]*/]
        as[String:Any])
}


//  DoneButton to submit everthing :)
@IBAction func DoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
  uploadImageToFirebase(imageData: imageUploaded)
    createAlert(title: "Post has been submitted", message: "Going to home page")
    addPost()

}


func uploadImageToFirebase(imageData: Data) {
    // References and vars
    let StorageRefrenece = Storage.storage().reference()
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let posterImageRef = StorageRefrenece.child("posters").child(currentUser!.uid).child("posterOne.jpg")

    let uploadMetaData = StorageMetadata()
    uploadMetaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    // putData to put data to the server using MetaData to orignize everthing.
    posterImageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: uploadMetaData) { (uploadedImageMeta, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error Took place \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            return
        } else {
            print("metaData of uploaded image \(uploadMetaData)")
        }
    }

    posterImageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            // Handle any errors
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            print("NOOOPPPEEE")
        } else {
            // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
            print("Working Good")
            let UrlString = url!.absoluteString
            print(UrlString)
            self.URLtoRealtime = UrlString
        }

    }


}
```

I'm trying like to make URLString = URLtoRealtime data and then 
add the post to firebase.
but what is happening is that it executes addPost() function before 
self.URLtoRealtime = UrlString

I don't know how to make the program to execute the previous line of code before addpost() function.

Comment: It happens like that because firebase calls are asynchronous. There are questions and answers similar to yours, you need to have a callback, escaping closure from your uploadImageToFirebase method, and then call addPost method inside the closure. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251463/how-can-i-return-an-object-that-i-create-in-my-data-service-class-through-fireba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return an object that I create in my data service class through Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251463/how-can-i-return-an-object-that-i-create-in-my-data-service-class-through-fireba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the done button is touched, you're asynchronously uploading the image to firebase and downloading the URL. However, as you've pointed out, by the time you `addPost`, the URL hasn't been downloaded yet – you want to do one after the other.

```
@IBAction func DoneButton(_ sender: Any) {
    uploadImageToFirebase(imageData: imageUploaded) { [weak self] (url, error) in
        if let url = url {
            createAlert(title: "Post has been submitted", message: "Going to home page")
            self?.URLtoRealtime = url.absoluteString
            self?.addPost()
        } else {
            self?.createAlert(title: "Post could not be submitted", message: "Try again")
        }
    }
}
```

We can add a completion argument to the upload method so that you can `addPost` once the upload and download of the URL is finished.

```
func uploadImageToFirebase(imageData: Data, completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?) -> ()) {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return completion(nil, nil) }

    let posterImageRef = Storage.storage().reference(withChild: "posters/\(uid)/posterOne.jpg")
    let uploadMetaData = StorageMetadata(dictionary: [ "contentType": "image/jpeg" ])

    posterImageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: uploadMetaData) { (metadata, error) in
        if let ref = metadata?.storageReference {
            ref.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                completion(url, error)
            })
        } else {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted ur code. when I upload the image it always drives me to "Post could not be submitted"

Comment: If you're not getting a url, you might be getting an error. What happens when you print it after the alert?

Comment: I have adjusted ur 2nd code to make it fit to my project and it's working now. Thnx :))))